# SQL Server Procedure Returning -1

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Executing a SQL Server stored procedure through VB.Net The stored procedure execute properly and return value. However, when it is executed through the VB.Net it's returning value -1.

Source code from VB.NET

```
Dim cmdSPStagingToPROD As New SqlCommand
Dim cnStagingToPROD As SqlConnection
Dim SPResponse As String

cmdSPStagingToPROD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmdSPStagingToPROD.Parameters.Add("@responseMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
cmdSPStagingToPROD.Parameters("@responseMessage").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

cnStagingToPROD = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
cnStagingToPROD.Open()

cmdSPStagingToPROD.Connection = cnStagingToPROD

SPResponse = cmdSPStagingToPROD.ExecuteNonQuery()

If SPResponse = "Success" Then
    StagingToPROD = "Success"
Else
    StagingToPROD = "Error"
    ErrorText = "Staging to PROD error " & SPResponse
End If
```

Expecting SET @responseMessage = 'Success' to return 'Success' or 'Error'

Comment: Using a return parameter is perhaps a bit of an overkill compared to using [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Your assigning the value to an output param so to fetch that value after execution you need to read:

```
cmdSPStagingToPROD.Parameters("@responseMessage").Value.ToString()
```

Currently you get -`1` as `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected - but as you `SET NOCOUNT ON` it will not be populated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the output parameter `@responseMessage`, after executing the command.
This way:

```
cmdSPStagingToPROD.Execute()
SPResponse = cmdSPStagingToPROD.Parameters("@responseMessage").Value
```